# How to left align footer element

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am getting problem in alignment of element that is in FooterTemplate of GridView.
Anyone suggest me how to do it.The Code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvComment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
OnRowDataBound="gvComment_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="gvComment_RowCreated" Width="100%" ShowHeader="false" BorderWidth="0px" ShowFooter="true">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
    <tr>
     <td valign="middle" align="left" style="width:10%"><img id="imgUser" src="" alt="" title="" runat="server" /></td>
     <td align="left" valign="top">
      comment comment
      <asp:Label ID="lblNameComments" runat="server" Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:7px;"></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" style="padding-top:10px;background-image:url(../Images/dotted_line.jpg);background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:center;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="height:7px;"></td></tr>
   </table>            
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField>
  <FooterTemplate >
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
   <tr>
    <td align="left">
     Footer Text
       Footer Text
       Footer Text         
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have set align property of td left but it doesn't work.Page output shown in image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does align left.

Please put complete code (css included) here:
http://jsfiddle.net/T364r/